# Profile data merged on change of email

Tags: support, tags, email, merge-accounts

I have changed my email id in `stackoverflow`, on change of it, my `tags`, `watched tags` etc., were merged from the previous account which i have deleted.

to elaborate

Consider I have an account with email id `test1@example.com` &
another account which i am not using with email id `test2@example.com`

Now I deleted my unused account `test2@example.com`

Later I changed the `email` of my `test1@example.com` account to `test2@example.com`

Then all my tags are inconsistent and my watched tags are merged with my old account

Can i know how to have my `tags` to be restored

You observe from image below, the inconsistency between the number of answers and the tags

[image: screenshot of my profile]

Comment: I wonder if this is caching. Have you posted something or got a vote since then?

Comment: yes, I have posted an answer just now, But it doesn't change the tags, & i remember reading somewhere that the tags will be calculated on a daily basis at some fixed time

Comment: as i mentioned in my comment, my tags are recalculated today and all my tags are restored

Comment: It seems that a deleted account isn't really deleted properly.